# What base64 format to use for images in opendocument/odt <office:binary-data>, possibly base64ing with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, base64, opendocument

I'm attempting to save an image base64'ed with nodejs in a raw format to an ODT file for display in OpenOffice Writer.

[The spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part1.html#a10_4_5_office_binary-data_) was not very clear, but I found [an example](http://www.datypic.com/sc/odf/e-draw_image.html). However, when I post the following base64'd image (that looks fine in html), I get a "Read-error" in OpenOffice and the image does not display.

The spec says that it uses rfc2045, but that [spec is not very specific](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) (unless I'm missing something).

Here's what I have:

```xml
<text:p text:style-name="qr-wrapper">
    <draw:frame draw:name="img1" svg:width="150.0pt" svg:height="150.0pt">
        <draw:image xlink:href="Pictures/0.png" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad">
            <office:binary-data>
                iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAACWCAIAAACzY+a1AAAABGdBTUEAA1teXP8meAAABjpJREFUeAHtm92OHTcMg7tF3/+VtwlaBB+8Q0Eee46HAHOlkSlaJmMLm5+v7+/vv/LLWYG/nZtP778ViIX2vw9iYSy0V8D+ALmFsdBeAfsD5BbGQnsF7A+QWxgL7RWwP0BuYSy0V8D+ALmFsdBeAfsD5BbGQnsF7A/wz40TfH193aiqSzp/87xrX+5FTubrbv9bZW0H38HM9vCLMw9pR9hXY2Lhq+3pNBcLOyq9GnNnFvJAN97uP+W7Zgl7UJwK08n/abgIyFPALpdUz5fgn8ncwp+amGVioZlhP9uNhT81McuszkIet/Omr8wMVct9Oxj2rOIOZ6dWYVSfCl/kcwsLcTyWYqGHT0WXsbAQx2Np5yx84sScSeTnLGFMPPOsZUw8851a4g/GuYUHxd+zdSzco+NBllh4UPw9W79xFnI+qZlETEcJ8rCWefJ0MMQfjHMLD4q/Z+tYuEfHgyyx8KD4e7beOQvVXJntVPHMzifi2QP5FYZ4YlhLDOMOhvjFOLdwUcDz5bHwvAeLHcTCRQHPl6/OQs6JXachZ2eudPDkUfhOXp2RtQrzUD638CFhP0cbCz+n9UM7xcKHhP0c7ReHxOe2LXfqzBXVNmsVptz8/8VdPJ29FjG5hYsCni+Phec9WOwgFi4KeL585yzk/ODJ1ExS+E4tMbti9jPbM/Ednl09/+LJLdwo5hmqWHhG9427xsKNYp6hujMLO299B8MTKzzzxKuYM0lhyEn8Sl7tpfKdfVXtkM8tHATx+4yFfp4NHcfCQRC/zzuzcPaUnDGztZwZs7Ud/Gxv7Ie1zKt9iSemU0v8EOcWDoL4fcZCP8+GjmPhIIjf551ZyDed77jKU5UOhnjGs7XEk4c9M088MSrPWhV3ajsYxf8rn1tYiOOxFAs9fCq6jIWFOB5LO/8dKeeHOj0xnRlADDlVnvzEq5g8rN2VV5yqnxv53MIbor2rJBa+y48b3cTCG6K9q2R1FnbeemJ4epXnHJrFs5b8zJOTcQezi3OWh30OcW7hIIjfZyz082zoOBYOgvh9rv4ZKU/M9515FavZQx6FUZyztcSTU+07iycna2f5yTPEuYWDIH6fsdDPs6HjWDgI4ve5cxZ2Ts95oPCdOUEMOVfyqp9OXvXAWmKYVz0TU8S5hYU4Hkux0MOnostYWIjjsbTzz0hnT8wZwFo1M4hRsaplfnbfWbzqjXlysjdimnFuYVOo98Ji4Xu9aXYWC5tCvRd25+dCnoZvOvMqnn33yd+p3YXfxUMdZjlZW8S5hYU4Hkux0MOnostYWIjjsXTn50L1pjPfOT3xnHOdPPlZyzxjxclahenk1V7MPxTnFj4k7OdoY+HntH5op1j4kLCfo139uZCdcmYwz3nDPGNVS4ziYa3CkKcTK07mydPZd6WWew1xbuEgiN9nLPTzbOg4Fg6C+H2uzsLO+04MZ8auvFJd8Ss886xlfjZW51U8xCvMkM8tHATx+4yFfp4NHcfCQRC/z9VZ+MSJOYc4G5jnvsQw34k7nMR09iKePbC2g2FtEecWFuJ4LMVCD5+KLmNhIY7H0urfF+46JecEOTkzOhjWqpg8jLkXY8VDDHmIZ554hWG+GecWNoV6LywWvtebZmexsCnUe2F3ZiFPw7ee+U7cmQ0Ko/LcV/U2W6vwip89MJ7Fs7aIcwsLcTyWYqGHT0WXsbAQx2NpdRbylGpmELNrHuziYW+duHNG8ig8+yeGefIUcW5hIY7HUiz08KnoMhYW4ngs7ZyFu06sZoPKc98OhngVr/Cw9gn+gTO3cBDE7zMW+nk2dBwLB0H8Pt84C6mimivMq5+liCEn8bMY1pKTPMSofKeWmCLOLSzE8ViKhR4+FV3GwkIcj6Wds5AzYOX0T/BwJqneuC/xzLNWYZgnnjExip/4Is4tLMTxWIqFHj4VXcbCQhyPpdVZyDf91InZQ2eurODVGRUn86p2MZ9buCjg+fJYeN6DxQ5i4aKA58vf+P8Lz6ti1UFuoZVdV83GwitVrHKx0Mquq2Zj4ZUqVrlYaGXXVbOx8EoVq1wstLLrqtlYeKWKVS4WWtl11WwsvFLFKhcLrey6ajYWXqlilYuFVnZdNRsLr1SxysVCK7uumo2FV6pY5f4FHaQ4Pt0WyyMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
            </office:binary-data>
        </draw:image>
    </draw:frame>
</text:p>
```

I could use a base64 conversion library, like for instance [this nodejs one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-format). What format is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, folks the answer is as follows:

```xml
<text:p text:style-name="qr-wrapper">
    <draw:frame draw:name="img1" svg:width="150.0pt" svg:height="150.0pt">
        <draw:image xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad">
            <office:binary-data>
                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
            </office:binary-data>
        </draw:image>
    </draw:frame>
</text:p>
```

That is to say

- the encoding cannot be prefixed with `data:image/png;base64,`
- the `<draw:image>` element cannot have a `xlink:href="Pictures/0.png"` attributed. Even though the spec says it will be ignored if `<office:binary-data>` is present. Shrug.